# How does Martin Heidegger want us to react to anxiety?

Tags: metaphysics, nietzsche, existentialism, phenomenology, heidegger

### **Introduction**:

After the world of das Man loses its significance and becomes meaningless, one falls in anxiety and he's able to embrace other possibilities.

But this anxiety is converted automatically into certain manifestations:

> This anxiety cannot be located. As Rollo May says, "it attacks us from
> all sides at once." A fear that can neither be understood nor located
> cannot be confronted and becomes more terrible still: it begets a
> feeling of helplessness which invariably generates further anxiety.
> (Freud felt that anxiety was a reaction to helplessness; anxiety, he
> wrote, "is a signal which announces that there is danger" and the
> individual is "expecting a situation of helplessness to set in." How
> can we combat anxiety? By displacing it from nothing to something.
> This is what Kierkegaard meant by "the nothing which is the object of
> dread becomes, as it were, more and more a something."
>
> > (**Existential psychotherapy, p43**)

These manifestations can be phobias and obsessions:

> Thus, neurotic symptoms serve to reduce and narrow—to magically
> transform the world so that he may be distracted from the concerns of
> death, guilt, and meaninglessness.
>
> > **(Humanistic psychiatry: from oppression to choice, pp. 123)**

### **Question**:

(A)
Unlike Nietzsche and his self-creation, does Heidegger want us to remain at anxiety and not choose to become anything even a self-created self?

So that if man came to terms with anxiety and its manifestations, he avoids the extra guilt of neurosis, but nevertheless still suffers from anxiety and its manifestations.

But what's the outcome to man from his suffering of anxiety?

(B)
Or, does he want us to abandon anxiety and become ourselves instead of das Man, but if so, i cannot find a difference between being ourselves or das Man: both of them seem inauthentic modes of being as they hinder of us of considering other possibilities of what we can be.

Comment: I see a paradox in Heidegger's, so i said it might be something in my reading.

Comment: In not letting Das Mann determine you, and being yourself, you may find that *yourself is nothing but the free play of possibilities itself*. Without any cultural form or idea of yourself you subscribe to, you are free to actually be that self unmediated by concept. I think the point may be that by subscribing to a self definition offered by your culture, you limit your possibilities for experience and being.

Comment: @EthanNOPE but being yourself is the same as being the culture's self in terms of inauthenticity, because both of them are lies that make man deny his mortality.

Comment: Not (B), sure. Authenticity should accept the prospect of Anxiety. Note, however, (i) that doesn't mean we must want Anxiety, (ii) or that we are able to stay authentic all the time.

Comment: Besides, in your question you are citing mostlly Rollo May who isn't strictly a heideggerian; only "das man" term in the question signifies the presence of Heidegger. Are you after Heidegger or after other "existentialists" too?

Comment: I am after Heidegger but i wanted to show the disadvantages of anxiety to one's psychology, so there is no outcome to an individual from it.

Comment: So you would not agree that _memento mori_ is worthy?

Comment: It's an unrealistic idealism.

Answer (score 1):

*(A) does Heidegger want us to remain at anxiety and not choose to become anything ...*

*(B) Or, does he want us to abandon anxiety and become ourselves ...*

He want us to accept the inevitable causes of anxiety: our finitude and mortality, or vulnerability in general.  He want us to realise this is the case (being 'free for death'), accept it and get on with life with the clear vision of the situation.

It's rather in line with Buddhist understanding of impermanence, but leading to a more determined (resolute) form of detachment (in which anxiety is still felt but not identified with).  Detachment nevertheless founded on care (*metta* in Buddhism).  One gives up caring about the disadvantage of mortality and gets on with taking care of things.

In this way it *is* an 'abandonment of anxiety' (B) by the method of accepting, not fearing, its causes.  The anxiety may still manifest but it washes over without wetting.

See *Being & Time*, H.384-385, (pages 436-437, tr. Macquarrie & Robinson)

> Dasein can be reached by the blows of fate only because in the depths
> of its Being Dasein *is* fate in the sense we have described. Existing
> fatefully in the resoluteness which hands itself down, Dasein has been
> disclosed as Being-in-the-world both for the 'fortunate' circumstances
> which 'come its way' and for the cruelty of accidents. ...
>
> If Dasein, by anticipation, lets death become powerful in itself,
> then, as free for death, Dasein understands itself in its own
> *superior power*, the power of its finite freedom, so that in this freedom, which 'is' only in its having chosen to make such a choice,
> it can take over the *powerlessness* of abandonment to its having done
> so, and can thus come to have a clear vision for the accidents of the
> Situation that has been disclosed. ...
>
> Fate is that powerless superior power which puts itself in readiness
> for adversities—the power of projecting oneself upon one's own
> Being-guilty, and of doing so reticently, with readiness for anxiety.
> As such, fate requires as the ontological condition for its
> possibility, the state of Being of care­—that is to say, temporality.
> Only if death, guilt, conscience, freedom, and finitude reside
> together equiprimordially in the Being of an entity as they do in
> care, can that entity exist in the mode of fate; that is to say, only
> then can it be historical in the very depths of its existence.
>
> *Only an entity which, in its Being, is essentially* **futural** *so that it is free for its death and can let itself be thrown back upon its
> factical "there" by shattering itself against death—that is to say,
> only an entity which, as futural, is equiprimordially in the process
> of* **having-been**, *can, by handing down to itself the possibility it has
> inherited, take over its own thrownness and be* **in the moment of vision**
> *for 'its time'. Only authentic temporality which is at the same time
> finite, makes possible something like fate—that is to say, authentic
> historicality.*

The process of 'having-been' is the futural perspective of present activity (informed by experience).  Planning and imagining the future is futural—which one can get on with when not paralysed by anxiety and fear of the future.

Answer (score 0):

Self-created self - it is nonsense.

Nietzsche's self-creating is without "pre" self. It is "ecce homo"ing. Self-created self - it is a circle logical fallacy. Self created self for self being... Do you know that homo first mean is a slave? So, self it is a slave. But whose is a slave is he. Yourself - mean our slave. Slave belongs to others. So, Nietzsche say: be self slave, only, own slave, not others. But Heidegger say: don't be a slave, be nothing.

*freedom is fiction, it is appeared after slaves rebellion, and freedom have it meaning only if someone haven't it. But this fiction is in base of any sociality group, it is a base of sociality structure. But, reality is more wide then sociality base - social reality. So if u are in freedom area - u can't be nothing except yourself subordination, self subordination to "many thou"="you" - mass others, das man.

But slave who knows that he is slave is not a slave, can be not a slave. Human who knows that he is "ecce homo" - is not himself. He is something but not self.
So, how to feel self? Anxiety is this feeling. That is why it needed.

Does Haidegger want to react on anxiety. I think nope. Cuz reaction it is slaves behavior. So, Hidegger had let anxiety to be, without reaction. It is needed to answer what is being without self - existentia, zero selfish being.